# Image from database not showing when organizing the code in classes

Tags: php, sql, database, image, mysqli

I'm having an issue with the images I get from my database when I organize my code in classes.

This is the code that works:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("XXXX","XXXX","XXX","XXXXXX");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Error al conectar: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `imagenes` WHERE id_imagenes=".$_GET["id"]);
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

header("Content-type:".$row["tipo_imagenes"]);
echo $row["imagen_imagenes"];
```

but when I make it like below this, it doesn't work. It shows the broken image icon:

[ imagen.php ]

```
require('../includes/php/config.php');

$imagen_trae= new imagen(); 
$imagen = $imagen_trae->traerImagen(); 

header("Content-type:".$imagen["tipo_imagenes"]);
echo $imagen["imagen_imagenes"];
```

[ config.php ]

```
require('conexion.php');

include_once('imagen_class.php');
```

[ conexion.php ]

```
define('DB_HOST','xxxxx'); 
define('DB_USER','xxxx'); 
define('DB_PASS','xxxxx'); 
define('DB_NAME','xxxx'); 
define('DB_CHARSET','utf-8'); 

class conexion 
{ 
    protected $_db; 

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $this->_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME); 

        if ( $this->_db->connect_errno ) 
        { 
            echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: ". $this->_db->connect_error; 
            return;     
        } 

        $this->_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET); 
    } 
}
```

[ imagen_class.php ]

```
class imagen extends conexion 
{ 

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function traerImagen() 
    {
        $result=$this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE id_imagenes=".$_GET["id"]);
        $imagenes_todas=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        return $imagenes_todas; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try catching exceptions - your code assumes calls return as expected. Functions return false to allow you to check and deal with errors.

Comment: could it be that the constants you define at the beginning of the `conexion` class are not actually part of the class and therefore are not initialised when you invoke the `parent::__construct()` method in the `imagen` class?

Comment: Don't do this: `"SELECT * FROM \`imagenes\` WHERE id_imagenes=".$_GET["id"]`. Injection potential.

Comment: Guys! Thanks for your help, I've modified all those security tips you gave me but it's a freaking poltergeist! The variables bring the data from the base when I do an echo, taking them out fo the header("Content-type:.. . $imagen["tipo_imagenes"] and $imagen["imagen_imagenes"]; yet it's not transformed into an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works for me.
the only possibility is the $_GET is not handed over to `imagen.php`
To **test** set $_GET["id"] to an Excisting **id**

[ imagen.php ]

```
$_GET["id"]=existing_id;
require('../includes/php/config.php');

$imagen_trae= new imagen(); 
$imagen = $imagen_trae->traerImagen(); 

header("Content-type:".$imagen["tipo_imagenes"]);
echo $imagen["imagen_imagenes"];
```

Also don't let the code run if there is no connection !!
A simple **return** is not enough.
**set `$this->_db` to `null` before return**

```
class conexion 
{ 
protected $_db; 

public function __construct() 
{ 
    $this->_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME); 

    if ( $this->_db->connect_errno ) 
    { 
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: ". $this->_db->connect_error; 
        $this->_db = null;
        return;     
    }
```

**and test it**

```
class imagen extends conexion 
{ 

public function __construct() 
{ 
    parent::__construct(); 
} 

public function traerImagen() 
{
    if ($this->_db != null) {
    $result=$this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE id_imagenes=".$_GET["id"]);
    $imagenes_todas=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $imagenes_todas; 
    } else return null;
```

Comment: Guys! Thanks for your help, I've modified all those security tips you gave me but it's a freaking poltergeist! The variables bring the data from the base when I do an echo, taking them out fo the header("Content-type:.. . 
$imagen["tipo_imagenes"] and $imagen["imagen_imagenes"]; yet it's not transformed into an image!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys!

I had to remove the require config.php (file that has the conection, all the other classes and functions) and replace it for the ones just needed to show the image. I ommited wirting down all the things I had in config.php because I didn't want to make my question too long but I guess that something inside those files was breaking the image or something.

Thanks again for having the time to read it and replying. I got some great tips!